# Using discord.js to detect image and respond

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a prank Discord bot for my friend's Discord server,
but the bot won't respond to anything; not even the elseif function passes.
If anyone know why my code isn't working can you please specify it.

NOTE: Client variable is Discord.Client if you needed a reference.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.channel.id != 425328056777834506) return;
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(4))== 3 && message.embeds.length > 0) {
    message.channel.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/330441704073330688/453693702687162369/yeet.png");
  } else if (message.embeds.length < 0) {
    message.channel.send("send me photos of your win >.>");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Message have a [attachments](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) property which you can use to get a collection of attached file(s) to a message (if any)

You can do a `if (message.attachments.size > 0)` to check for any attached objects first.
Afterwards, you can loop through the collection and check if the attached file URL ends with a `png` or `jpeg`.

```
if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    if (message.attachments.every(attachIsImage)){
        //something
    }
}
        
...
        
function attachIsImage(msgAttach) {
    var url = msgAttach.url;
    //True if this url is a png image.
    return url.indexOf("png", url.length - "png".length /*or 3*/) !== -1;
}
```

**EDIT**

For your bot not responding to anything. Make sure that you are testing the bot in the channel that has the same ID in the `message.channel.id != 425328056777834506` statement.
(Or you can comment out that if statement first, then add that in when your bot is fully functional.)

Also, `client.on("message", message => {...` gets called when your bot sends a message too. You can do `if (message.author.id == <YourBotID>) {return;}` to let the bot ignore it's own messages.
Or you can do `if (message.author.bot) {return;}` if you want it to ignore messages sent by other bots.

Comment: Is this why my bot isn't replying to anything?

Comment: also do you know why this is looping "ah" several times

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.channel.id != 425328056777834506) return;
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(4))=== 3 && message.attachments.length > 0) {
    message.channel.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/330441704073330688/453693702687162369/yeet.png");
  } else if (message.attachments.length === 0) {
    message.channel.send("test");
  }
  message.channel.send("ah");
})

Comment: @XeonNetwork I edited my question, it should explain why to you.

Comment: I did what you said but the bot still won't reply, full snippet of code: https://pastebin.com/raw/f72Yqe37

Comment: At the start, it's `client.on`, not `client.once`. Also, place a semi-colon at the end, though unlikely, that might be the problem too.

Comment: The bot responds now but the if statement is still not passing with message.attachments.length

Comment: I just logged the length of the attachment and I got undefined

Comment: Sorry, I meant `size` property instead of `length`.

Comment: Last 2 questions, how do you find those properties and is there any table functions in javascript?

Comment: Search through the DiscordJS documentation. You can find the properties of attachments here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments . Also I am not really sure what you meant by tables, but you can create a multi-dimensional array, google that up.

Comment: can you mind helping me in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769491/variable-for-toggle-function-and-enabling-disabling

Comment: To let you know that other formats exist (eg. WebP), it's not necessary that having a extension at the end would surely be an image, data could be entirely different. Also, multiple aliases for extensions exist (eg. `.apng` is PNG file too).