# Discord.js v12 image in message embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

I would like to make a vouch system but with images, when they take screenshot with lightshot to copy the image and paste it to discord chat and when it's been sent, bot will upload it in embed.

My current attempt:

```js
client.on("message", message => {

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (message.channel.id == `912767631344423032`) { //Channel ID
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    message.delete();
    const vch = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Feedback`)
      .setColor("#F3950D")
      .setDescription(`<a:bluefire:911708697988845569> Vouched By:\n**${message.author.tag}**`)
      .setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/911530458637033514/a_d62f915")
      .setImage(`${message.content}`)
      .setFooter("Created and Developed by Tana#6969 ❤️")
    message.channel.send(vch)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What does it do now? Like you haven't shown any errors or any parts where we can see the problem is at.
2. Message.content relates to the message content (text), if no message content (text) is sent it will result into null. You would need to get the image from the attachment option. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When I upload the image to discord and send it, it just sends the embed but with no content of image in

Answer (score -1):

There is a lot of ways of doing this, you can go to google and look for a picture that suits you, then right-click it and click "Copy image link" or something similar, or you can do the same but on discord, by sending the image you want then opening it then right-clicking it then choose "Copy image link" or something similar.

Comment: I know what you mean, you miss understood me tho haha. So I want people to upload "saved" images from their pc directly to a discord channel with no link.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I don't really know how to get the content of a message if it's an image, maybe this can help?
[This](https://newbedev.com/javascript-get-link-of-an-image-discord-js-code-example) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710598/using-discord-js-to-detect-image-and-respond)

I wish this at latest helps!