# How detect image in a message from the server users and reply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Firts, sorry for my poor english

I start to learn js and I want to detect image in a message from the server users and reply this in an embed, bot message.content not working for that.

```
 if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefi}tw`)) { // the command for te announcement
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#3ded97") //message line color "Green"
    .setImage(msg.content()) //Image from the message 
    .setFooter(`God • ${dia.toLocaleDateString()}`); //The base from the text with date and the sender
msg.delete(); //Delete the message from the user 
msg.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Thanks my friends :'') H

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using discord.js to detect image and respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710598/using-discord-js-to-detect-image-and-respond)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could get the image by using `msg.attachments.url` which returns the url of the message attachment (in this case an image)

Doc : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageAttachment

Also, if you're using discord.js V13, to send embeds I think you should use `msg.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })` instead of `msg.channel.send(embed)`

**Edit** : If you're using discord.js V12 or greater, use `MessageEmbed()` instead of `RichEmbed()`